# Bash script - run process & send to background if good, or else

Tags: bash, redirect, ubuntu-14.04

I need to start up a Golang web server and leave it running in the background from a bash script.  If the script in question in syntactically correct (as it will be most of the time) this is simply a matter of issuing a

```
go run /path/to/index.go &
```

However, I have to allow for the possibility that index.go is somehow erroneous.  I should explain that in Golang this for something as "trival" as importing a module that you then fail to use.  In this case the `go run /path/to/index.go` bit will return an error message.  In the terminal this would be something along the lines of

```
index.go:4:10: expected...
```

What I need to be able to do is to somehow change that command above so I can funnel any error messages into a file for examination at a later stage.  I tried variants on `go run /path/to/index.go >> errors.txt` with the terminating & in different positions but to no avail.

I suspect that there is a bash way to do this by altering the priority of evaluation of the command via some judiciously used braces/brackets etc.  However, that is way beyond my bash capabilities.  I would be most obliged to anyone who might be able to help.

### Update

A few minutes later... After a few more experiments I have found that this works

```
go run /path/to/index.go &> errors.txt &
```

Quite apart from the fact that I don't in fact understand why it works there remains the issue that it produces a 0 byte errors.txt file when the command goes to completion without Golang throwing up any error messages.  Can someone shed light on what is going on and how it might be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narūnas K's answer covers why the `&>` redirection works.

The reason why the file is created anyway is because the shell creates the file before it even runs the command in question.

You can see this by trying `no-such-command > file.out` and seeing that even though the shell errors because `no-such-command` doesn't exist the file gets created (using `&>` on that test will get the shell's error in the file).

This is why you can't do things like `sed 'pattern' file > file` to edit a file in place.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Does this mean I have to live with the zero byte file or woud it be possible to test for zero and delete it in an extended version of the command that worked above?

Comment: You can test the file for size and delete it when the process is finished if you want, but otherwise, yes, you get to live with it. (Using `2>&1 | tee ...` or similar might not write the file if `tee` sees no content but you'd have to try it and it involves an extra process, a sub-shell and sends the output to screen/terminal as well as the file.)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from `man bash`.

> Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error
>
> ```
>    This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the file whose name is the expansion of word.   
>
>    There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
>           &>word
>    and
>           >&word
>
>    Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically equivalent to
>
>           >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> Appending Standard Output and Standard Error
>
> ```
>    This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be appended to the file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
>    The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
>
>           &>>word
>
>    This is semantically equivalent to
>
>           >>word 2>&1
> ```